# Create a script that connect to wifi, and if it fails fallback to ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I'd like to create a script that tries to connect me to the wifi specified by my wpa_supplicant conf, and if it fails, create a ad-hoc network. But I'm struggling with it.

Here is what I do for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create adhoc network function
createAdHocNetwork(){
    echo "Creating ad-hoc network"
    ifconfig wlan0 down
    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
    iwconfig wlan0 essid AccessPoint
    ifconfig wlan0 11.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    echo "Ad-hoc network created"
}

# connect to wifi function
connect(){
    echo "Trying to connect to configured wifi"
    ifdown wlan0
    wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /home/pi/pics/wpa_supplicant.conf
    ifup wlan0
    echo "Wifi configured"
}

echo "================================="
echo "Wifi setup"
echo "================================="
connect
echo "Checking connectivity..."
sleep 5s
ping -c 5 -I wlan0 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1
PINGSTATUS=$?
echo "Status"
echo $PINGSTATUS
if [ $PINGSTATUS -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "Connected to WiFi"
    else
        echo "Wifi not connected, fallback to ad-hoc"
        createAdHocNetwork
fi

exit 0
```

It seems it works to connect to the configured wifi, but not for ad-hoc.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# start interfaces upon start of the system
auto lo wlan0

# register loopback interface
iface lo inet loopback

# use dhcp and allow interface to be started when kernel detects a hotplug event
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# use manual ip configuration for wlan0 interface and allow hotplug as well
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

And my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 11.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 11.0.0.2 11.0.0.150;
}
```

I can see the ad-hoc network from other computer, but I cannot connect to it, any idea?

Regards

Comment: No, no error message

Comment: Did you check both sides for these error messages when attempting to connect to the ad-hoc network?

Comment: Can you show the output of "iwlist wlan0 s" (or equivalent command) from the computer trying to connect to the newly created ad-hoc network? How are you trying to connect to the ad-hoc network (terminal, GUI)? The only thing I noticed is that you don't specify a channel for the ad-hoc network, though I'd assume that it would default to Channel 1.

Comment: I can connect to the ad-hoc network while outside the script. There's nothing wrong with my hardware, I'm 1000% sure.